# iPhone silencing text messages on Do Not Disturb even if contact is on favorite and Emergency Bypass

Tags: ios, do-not-disturb

iPhone 7, iOS 12.1

I have a contact on my VIP (favorite) list and in the Do Not Disturb configuration I've enabled the option not to silence calls from that group.

The contact has also the Emergency Bypass option for calls and SMS's.

But when I receive a text from that contact when the DND mode is on, I get no sound notification.

**How do I ensure that I still get sound notifications for contacts not silenced in my Do Not Disturb settings?**